# Finding repetition while calculating list items

Tags: python, performance

I need to know if there exists an algorithm for finding the first repeated subset in an integer list while calculating said list.
For example, given a function which outputs in a for elements like this

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

I'd like to be able to break at the first occurrence of  the repetition, leaving only with

```
[1,2,3]
```

The reason being i don't want to calculate the whole list for performance reasons.
Is there any way? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to @milanbalazs's solution, which will not stop at single repeating elements, but on repeating sequences:

```
nums = [1,2,3,1,1,2,3,1]
result = []
for i, num in enumerate(nums):
    if result and result == nums[i:i+len(result)]:
        print(f'Found repetition: {result}')
        # Break the iteration when the sequence in result is the same
        # as the upcoming sequence in nums
        break 
    result.append(num)

print(f'Result: {result}')
```

#### Output

```
Found repetition: [1, 2, 3, 1]
Result: [1, 2, 3, 1]
```

Comment: Ty! I should have mentioned that i have repeated numbers that are part of the list...

Answer (score 1):

I have written an example code for you:

**Code:**

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
result = []
for num in nums:
    if num in result:
        break  # Break the iteration if the element already exists in the result list
    result.append(num)

print("Result: {}".format(result))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
Result: [1, 2, 3]
```